# trying to update geoip gets error -21 - It has been working until recently

Tags: geoip

I have been downloading the geoip lite database for a long time. However, something has changed somewhere that is causing an error -21. This is the verbose output:

```
sudo geoipupdate -v
Opened License file /etc/GeoIP.conf
Read in license key 000000000000
number of product ids 2
Connecting to MaxMind GeoIP server
via Host or Proxy Server: updates.maxmind.com:80
sending request GET /app/update_getfilename?product_id=506 HTTP/1.0
Host: updates.maxmind.com

database product id 506 database file name /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat
/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat can't be opened, proceeding to download database
MD5 sum of database /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat is 0000000000000000000000000000000
Connecting to MaxMind GeoIP Update server
sending request GET /app/update_getipaddr HTTP/1.0
Host: updates.maxmind.com
client ip address: 162.230.29.192
md5sum of ip address and license key is b2e7d4d48d92ec691a3f67b6d861e1bb
sending request GET    /app/update_secure?db_md5=0000000000000000000000000000000&challenge_md5=b2e7d4d48d92ec691a3f67b6d861e1bb&user_id=999999&edition_id=506 HTTP/1.0
Host: updates.maxmind.com

Downloading gzipped GeoIP Database...
Done
Updating /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat
Saving gzip file to /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat.gz ... download data to a gz file named /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCountry.dat.gz
Done
Uncompressing gzip file ... Done
Performing sanity checks ... Database type is 1
database_info  FAIL null
Received Error -21 (Sanity check database_info string failed) when    attempting to update GeoIP Database
Connecting to MaxMind GeoIP server
via Host or Proxy Server: updates.maxmind.com:80
sending request GET /app/update_getfilename?product_id=533 HTTP/1.0
Host: updates.maxmind.com

database product id 533 database file name /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat can't be opened, proceeding to download database
MD5 sum of database /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat is 0000000000000000000000000000000
md5sum of ip address and license key is b2e7d4d48d92ec691a3f67b6d861e1bb
sending request GET    /app/update_secure?db_md5=0000000000000000000000000000000&challenge_md5=b2e7d4d48d92ec691a3f67b6d861e1bb&user_id=999999&edition_id=533 HTTP/1.0
Host: updates.maxmind.com

Downloading gzipped GeoIP Database...
Done
Updating /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
Saving gzip file to /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz ... download data to a gz file named /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
Done
Uncompressing gzip file ... Done
Performing sanity checks ... Database type is 1
database_info  FAIL null
Received Error -21 (Sanity check database_info string failed) when attempting to update GeoIP Database
```

It is not clear to me if the dat files are not downloading (each gets that "can't be opened") message which may be normal. Or if there is something going on with the unzip that causes the update to fail the sanity check. Can someone help me figure this out? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

GeoLite Legacy has been [discontinued](https://support.maxmind.com/geolite-legacy-discontinuation-notice/). The error given by your version of `geoipupdate` does not seem particularly useful. Newer versions of `geoipupdate` say `404 Not Found: Database edition not found`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a free replacement or is it only pay now?

Comment: I guess there is but I need to find info on how to configure awstats with GeoIP2. So far can only find it for the legacy version.